# Terminal could not find command "$ php -v"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, php

I recently try to install ionCube loader and when I tried to check my PHP version via Terminal, it gave me an `-bash: $: command not found`.

How can I fixed that?

Answer (score 6):

The `$` is just an example for the shell prompt in whatever instruction guide you are reading (used to indicate that you should run the command from your standard user account. A `#` would indicate that you should run the command as an admin/root user). Just run

```
php -v
```

instead.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the `$` is included to indicate that the command should be run as the user, as opposed to `#` which indicates the command should be run as root.

Comment: @Liam Good point, even though I assume that people who are aware of the difference between `$` and `#` also know how to copy/paste commands from an instruction page :-)